# Bijective proof involving floor functions

Tags: number-theory

Could someone lead me in the direction of how to prove that this function is injective and surjective?

$f:\mathbb N→\mathbb N$ defined by $f(n)= (-1)^n \cdot \lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$

I understand what it means for a function to be injective and surjective, but I'm unsure how the floor function factors into this proof.

Comment: Try formatting your math with mathjax (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). The floor function is \lfloor...\rfloor ($\lfloor\cdots\rfloor$).

Comment: Do you mean as a function $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1):

To prove $f$ is injective, assume that $f(n) = f(k)$, and then reason about the resulting algebra until you conclude that $n = k$. Then you're done with that part.

You can show your work by editing your question, showing how far you got, and perhaps we can help you further.

To show $f$ is *surjective*, let $w$ be any element of $\Bbb N$ (or more likely $\Bbb Z$, as @egreg suggests), and see if you can figure out what element $n \in \Bbb N$ has $f(n) = w$. This'll be easiest if you divide into the cases $ w = 0, w > 0, w < 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If it wasn't for the floor function, $f$ would not have $\mathbb Z$ as codomain (following egreg I'm assuming that's what you mean). We have
$$f(1)=0, f(2)=1, f(3)=-1, f(4)=2,\ldots,$$
while the function $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb Q$ defined by $g(n)=(-1)^n\cdot\frac n2$ gives
$$g(1)=-\frac12, g(2)=1, g(3)=-\frac32, g(4)=2,\ldots$$
Is that enough of a hint to help you with the proof?

Answer (score 1):

> When I looked at the question I just assumed $0 \in \mathbb N$. So it
>   looks like my work answers a slightly different question. But the
>   ideas are what counts so I am leaving it as is.

When you examine

$\quad f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$
$\quad f(n)= (-1)^n \cdot \lfloor\frac{n+1}{2} \rfloor$

realize that several things are going on - you are multiplying two functions together, the floor function (with a change of variable) and $Alt(n) = (-1)^n$,  and adjusting the domain and codomain to get the function $f$.

If that is confusing, you can also directly define the function $f$ (actually a sequence). This might also be confusing, but sometimes doing the same thing in two different ways can add insight.

Define $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$ as follows:

$f(n) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        \;\;\;0\, \;\;\;\text{ |} & \text{for } n = 0\\
        -m \;\;\; \text{ |} & \text{for } n = 2m - 1\\
        +m \;\;\;\text{ |} & \text{for } n = 2m\\
         & \text{where } m \ge 1
        \end{array}\right\}$

Exercise 0: Check what $f$ does with the inputs $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, and $5$.

Exercise 1: Show that the two definitions for $f$ are indeed equivalent.

Exercise 2: Show, using the second formulation, that $f$ is a bijection.

Exercise 3: Show, using the original formulation, that $f$ is a bijection.